# Search text in all Disqus comments on a blog post

Tags: disqus

Many blogs now use Disqus. While its tree view and lazy loading of comments are in theory a good thing for handling hundreds of comments, the simple fact that it encourages a large number of comments makes it often impossible to read all comments before commenting myself.

However, I don't want to create a new comment-subtree for a point already raised by one or more other commenters and would like to search the comments for keywords. In traditional WordPress comments I can just use a browser's text search for this. Disqus' lazy-loading however makes this impossible.

Is there some way to search Disqus comments after all? A sufficient, maybe even preferred, solution would be a "show all comments for this blog post" function (as opposed to repeating "scroll to end, click 'more comments'" dozens of times) to make browser search useful again.